# How to sort the values from api in a listview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have points(Punkty) in api and I would like to sort it from highest to lowest number. ScoreBoard is listview.
 Sorry for my english.

```
  private async void GetAll()
    {
        var token = Application.Current.Properties["MyToken"].ToString();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("URL");

        var tablicaW = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RewardsGetALL>>(response);

        scoreBoard.ItemsSource = tablicaW;
    }
```

Class RewardGetAll:

```
  public class RewardsGetALL
{
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Punkty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1)

```
scoreBoard.ItemsSource = tablicaW.OrderByDescending(p => p.Punkty);
```